# Is symfony 2.0 stable enough to use?

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I wonder if **Symfony 2.0** is stable enough to use?

Because I've never used **Symfony** before.

It seems that **Symfony 2** is much better than the previous version and I don't want to relearn/recode everything some months from now.

When do you think it will be released?

Would it be a wise choice to use 2.0 now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>No.</strike>

Yes. http://symfony.com/download

<strike>http://symfony-reloaded.org/learn</strike>

Quote from above link:

> Please note that Symfony 2 is not yet ready for production. The final release is planned for late 2010 and will only support PHP 5.3.2. In the meantime, we highly encourage you to use the current symfony 1.4 stable release for all your projects.

Comment: But I cannot wait until it is.

Comment: is the code in symfony 2.0 very different from 1.4 so i have to relearn everything or is it almost the same so it wouldnt hurt to learn 1.4 now?

Comment: From what I see, the syntax is pretty different, but I would say that the philosophy is the same, MVC, Helpers, Partials, etc..

Comment: ahhhh...why isnt Symfony 2.0 and Doctrine 2.0 available!!!!!! would have made things more easy!

Comment: Maybe time to update this answer as SF2 has been out and stable for a while now?

Answer (score 4):

Symfony core team member here. No, Symfony2's not ready at all to be used in production, because it hasn't even reached the alpha state. As stated on the github page, things (especially the API) WILL change.

Furthermore, some components are not here yet, for example the Forms framework, so you would have to handle them by hand. Don't do that. But of course we'd be more than happy to get some feedback if you give it a try for a sandbox project of yours ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am excited about the release. Also, thank you for releasing the Symfony Live presentations and videos.

Comment: wish i could help u with testing it out, but im a rookie in symfony. so perhaps its better just to wait and use 1.4 meanwhile:) thanks for a great product!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that we ([www.exercise.com](http://www.exercise.com)) are live and have been using Symfony 2 for a while now.

It has not been the most smooth experience (we try to stay up to date with the most recent sf2 branches on git, which is almost a full-time job for 1 person), but we have built a functioning site.

The largest hurdle right now to starting a project is the lack of documentation and examples online. So while it is possible to run a production site using Symfony 2, the framework still has a long ways to go until it can be used for a small project.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday at SymfonyLive 2011 (Twitter #sflive2011) Fabien said that the first Release Candidate will be March 2011.